# Fast way to extract an array of datestrings from a table of datetimes MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, datetime

I have a 2million+ row by 1 column variable that is a table of cells with each cell containing one datetime (table_datetime).
I need to make an array of datestrings from this table (array_datetime).

My current code:

```
parfor i = 1:length(table_datetime)
    temp_cellstr = cellstr(table_datetime{i,1});
    temp_matstr = [cell2mat(temp_cellstr)];
    array_datetime(i,:) = [temp_matstr];
end
array_datetime = datestr(array_datetime,'mm.dd.yyyy HH:MM:SS');
```

Currently this is taking me around 40 minutes (using 2 workers in parallel).
The length of my table is very long, but is there a faster way to extract the datetimes from the table and convert them to an array of datestrings?

Comment: Hi, I suggest you have a look at [Tall Arrays](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/tall-arrays.html) (scroll down to Creating Tall Timetables) and maybe [datastore](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datastore.html), depending on how your data is stored

Answer (score 1):

You might well be better off using arrays of `datetime`, and then the vectorised methods that operate on those. I would do this:

```
array_datetime = vertcat(table_datetime{:});
array_datetime.Format = 'MM.dd.yyyy hh:mm:ss';
char_datetime = char(cellstr(array_datetime));
```

This portion took about ~12 seconds for 1e6 elements on my machine using R2017a.

You would be better off if you can not even forming the `cell` array of `datetime`, and instead just using an array of `datetime`.